# Codeigniter uploading image is not working

Tags: php, file-upload, codeigniter-3, image-upload

**Controller**

```
          public function addemployee()
          {
           $config['upload_path']  = './images/employee/';
           $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
           $config['max_size'] = 100;
           $config['max_width'] = 1024;
           $config['max_height'] = 768;

           $this->load->library('upload', $config);

          if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
          {
           $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
           $this->load->view('include/headerforms');
           $this->load->view('include/aside');
           $this->load->view('template/forms/employeeforms',$error);
           $this->load->view('include/footerforms'); 
          }
          else
          {
           $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data('userfile'));
           $data = [
          'userfile'   => './images/employee/' . $file['file_name'],
          'userfile' => $this->input->post('userfile'),
          'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
          'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
          'middlename'=> $this->input->post('middlename'),
          'lastname'=> $this->input->post('lastname'),
          'company'=> $this->input->post('company'),
          'department'=> $this->input->post('department'),
          'position'=> $this->input->post('position'),
          'address'=> $this->input->post('address'))
          ];
          $this->ci_db_model->addemployee($data);
```

> this portion is connect to my database

```
          $this->session->set_flashdata('message','New image has been added..');
          $this->load->view('include/header2');
          $this->load->view('include/aside');
          $this->load->view('template/employee');
          $this->load->view('include/footer2');
          }
         }
```

**View**

```
      <!-- Name -->
               <?php echo form_open_multipart('home/addemployee'); ?>
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputFile">Photo</label>
                  <input type="file" name"userfile" id="exampleInputFile" required>
                </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input name="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input name="middlename" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                  </div>
                </div>      
         <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit">
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Programming language : PHP Codeigniter
server: XAMPP

I'M BEGINNER!!

Question: How to upload image into database?

When I click the submit button there an error "You did not select a file to upload.".

What wrong with my code?

THANKS IN ADVANCE PLEASE HELP ANYONE.

Comment: Try printing $_FILES['userfile']['name'] before calling do_upload. Does it store the correct filename?

Answer (score 1):

controller

```
    if ((isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) && ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] != "")) {
                $file = "userfile";
                $path = './uploads/file/' ;
                $uploadedimages = $this->upload_image($file, $path, 1);
                $data['image'] = $uploadedimages['file_name'];
    }
```

/* Upload file  function */

```
public function upload_image($file, $path, $thumb) {

        /* Upload file  in posted */
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->load->library('upload');

        $image_upload_folder = $path;

        if (!file_exists($image_upload_folder)) {
            mkdir($image_upload_folder, DIR_WRITE_MODE, true);
        }
        @chmod($image_upload_folder, 0777);
        $this->upload_config = array(
            'upload_path' => $image_upload_folder,
            'allowed_types' => '*',
            'remove_space' => TRUE,
            'encrypt_name' => TRUE,
        );

        $this->upload->initialize($this->upload_config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file)) {
            $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            echo ($upload_error);

        } else {
            $file_info = $this->upload->data();

            if ($thumb == 1) {

                $this->image_lib->clear();
                $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
                $config['source_image'] = $image_upload_folder . '/' . $file_info['file_name'];
                $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                $config['thumb_marker'] = '_thumb';
                $config['master_dim'] = 'width';
                $config['quality'] = 100;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['width'] = 150;
                $config['height'] = 150;
                $config['new_image'] = $file_info['file_name'];

                //$this->image_lib->clear();
                //move_uploaded_file($value['full_path'], '/uploads/' . $newimagename);
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                //$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {

                    $this->image_lib->clear();
                    $data['file_name'] = $file_info['file_name'];
                    $data['file_thumb'] = $file_info['file_name'];


                } else {
                    $upload_error = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                                       $data['file_name'] = $file_info['file_name'];
                    $thmb = explode(".", $data['file_name']);
                    $data['file_thumb'] = $thmb[0] . "_thumb." . $thmb[1];
                }


                return $data;
            } else {
                return $file_info['file_name'];
            }
        }
    }
```